# Your license is not valid in diff tool

Tags: vb.net, diff, semantic-diff, semantic-merge

I've recently been trying out the [Semantic Merge](http://semanticmerge.com/) beta from Codice Software, suddenly when I try to use the diff tool (either within Visual Studio or manually from the desktop) I get the following error:

> Your license is not valid, you are not able to use the diff tool.  Please contact with support.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled, and I don't see a newer version or any updates to the product, and it was working yesterday.  Do I need to purchase a license for it, or is something broken on my machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that your current license is not valid for `VB.Net` (it is only valid for `CSharp`).

Our first beta, was only for `CSharp`, and maybe you already generated a trial for that beta.

In order to get the `Vb.Net` license, you need have to request a new license for the new language. So just follow these steps:

- Open the **SemanticMerge tool** (resolving a merge)
- Click the **Get License** button,
- Get your new license from the website

You can get it also from our [website](http://www.semanticmerge.com/users/) directly. Hope it helps.